# Match up values

Tags: excel, vba

Any idea on writing VBA code that takes values from one sheet and matches them to values in another sheet, one row at a time. Would display approval if all values matched up in perhaps a 3rd sheet, and if any don't match up it would show that pair that didn't match in another range on that 3rd sheet

Tried using VLOOKUP but don't know if that's the best way about it.

Code so far:

```
Sub MatchValues()
    matchStatus = matched
    For i = 1 To 4
        If WorksheetFunction.Round(ws1.Cells(6, i + 2).Value, -3) <> WorksheetFunction.Round(ws2.Cells(34, i + 35).Value, -3) Then
            matchStatus = "Values do not match"
        Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ws3.Range("B3").Value = matchStatus
    If matchStatus = "Values do not match" Then
        ws3.Range("B5").Value = "Sheet1: " & ws1.Cells(6, 3).Value & " - " & "Sheet2: " & ws2.Cells(34, 35).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service. Please post your existing code (as text) and explain what problem you have with it. Likely you will also need to clarify what you mean by "perhaps" a 3rd sheet ... code (VBA or otherwise) doesn't do "perhaps"!

Comment: Tried this so far:  Sub MatchValues()
(Dimensions etc)
    matchStatus = matched
    For i = 1 To 4
        If WorksheetFunction.Round(ws1.Cells(6, i + 2).Value, -3) <> WorksheetFunction.Round(ws2.Cells(34, i + 35).Value, -3) Then
            matchStatus = "Values do not match"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next 
    ws3.Range("B3").Value = matchStatus
    If matchStatus = "Values do not match" Then
        ws3.Range("B5").Value = "Sheet1: " & ws1.Cells(6, 3).Value & " - " & "Sheet2: " & ws2.Cells(34, 35).Value
    End If
End Sub

Comment: So do you want to tell us what problem you have with it and clarify what you mean by "perhaps" a 3rd sheet?

Comment: there is a shird sheet involved, yes. I mentioned perhaps because wasn't sure if that was the best place for the outcome, as opposed to a MsgBox. the problem with it was that it wasn't matching the correct cells

Comment: also, in the beginning I'd rounded prior to the VBA code but did want to incorporate rounding values in AV34:AY34 in sheet 2 to match up to C6:F6 in sheet 1- was stuck on where to add that in the code

Comment: I don't see your data example in your question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub CompareSheets()

'set your range
Topleft = "A1"
BottomRight = "C3"

'compare cells in this range between Sheet1 and Sheet2
For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Topleft & ":" & BottomRight)
    If cell.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value = "Matched"
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value = cell.Value & " not equal to " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```